# Angular Components: What is the difference between one-way and attribute bindings?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-bindings

I've been building a few angular components and was wondering what are the practical difference between the one-way ("<") and attribute ("@") bindings?

Are there scenarios where one is preferable over the other?  It is simple that attributes are always immutable strings and must be interpolated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component:

> @ bindings can be used when the input is a string, especially when the
>   value of the binding doesn't change.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

> "@" - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>   strings.
>
> "<" - set up a one-way (one-directional) binding between a
>   local scope property and an expression passed via the attribute

So, use '@' for passing string values. The value could be a simple string value, e.g. myattr="hello", or it could be an AngularJS interpolated string with embedded expressions, e.g. myattr="my_{{helloText}}".